# Keys problems when mapping using Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to get my monthly sales and put them on the chart. They're going to be grouped by year. This is what I've done so far:

```
let result = _
  .chain(res.data)
  .groupBy("_id.year")
  .value();
result = _.map(result, (yearlyValues, key) => {
  return {
    [key]: _.map(yearlyValues, yearlyValuesItems => {
      return {
        [yearlyValuesItems._id.month]: yearlyValuesItems.count
      };
    })
  };
});

result = _.map(result, (value, key) => {
  return _.map(value, (innerValues, innerKey) => {
    return innerValues;
  })
})
result = _.flatten(result);

result = _.map(result, (value, key) => {
  return _.map(value, (items, keys) => {
    return _.map(items, (a, b) => {
      return a
    })
  })
});

for (var i in result) {
  final_count.push(_.flatten(result[i]));
}

console.log(final_count);

$scope.labels_monthly = monthNames;
$scope.series = Object.keys(final_count);
$scope.data = Object.values(final_count);
$scope.options = {
  legend: {
    display: true
  }
};
```

My data: https://pastebin.com/WhJ0atTX
My output: https://jsfiddle.net/asfxtor4/1/

My problem is that [I am getting keys 0, 1, 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1rG1.png) instead of 2016, 2017, 2018.
And then inside I need to get key as a month number.[This key has to be 2 because the month is March, but it generates 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUMcg.png). You can see in the pictures.

This is my desired output: https://pastebin.com/iChhrnNG, I need to get an array of all months and if there is data for just March lets say, all other array elements should be 0.

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't exactly see what the desired output. What do you want the code to do that it's not doing?

Comment: publish example of desired result

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of objects with years and values by adding 'entries' e.g.

```
let result = _
      .chain(data)
      .groupBy("_id.year")
      .entries()
      .value()
      .map((item) => ({year: item[0], values: item[1]}));
```

You then won't need:

```
result = _.map(result, (yearlyValues, key) => {
 return {
 [key]: _.map(yearlyValues, yearlyValuesItems => {
  return {
    [yearlyValuesItems._id.month]: yearlyValuesItems.count
  };
 })
 };
});
```

You can see a fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/yr8bqteL/

Hopefully this info will help you complete this assignment.

Comment: Here result is array of objects. What I need is array for each year. Lets suppose there are 2017 and 2018. I need to get two arrays with counts for specific year and if there are no orders in some month there must be 0. For example: 2017: [5,6,8,9,0,4,5,68,46,21,0,14] ...etc.so there are no orders in May and October. I think you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know you always have 12 months you could be somewhat less fancy and do this:

```js
data = [{
    "_id": {
      "month": 12,
      "year": 2018
    },
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 11,
      "year": 2018
    },
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 9,
      "year": 2018
    },
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 8,
      "year": 2018
    },
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 5,
      "year": 2018
    },
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 7,
      "year": 2018
    },
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 4,
      "year": 2018
    },
    "count": 5
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 9,
      "year": 2017
    },
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 8,
      "year": 2017
    },
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 11,
      "year": 2017
    },
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 10,
      "year": 2017
    },
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 4,
      "year": 2017
    },
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 2,
      "year": 2017
    },
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 6,
      "year": 2017
    },
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 1,
      "year": 2018
    },
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 2,
      "year": 2018
    },
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 3,
      "year": 2018
    },
    "count": 9
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 10,
      "year": 2018
    },
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 3,
      "year": 2017
    },
    "count": 9
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 7,
      "year": 2017
    },
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 12,
      "year": 2017
    },
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 3,
      "year": 2016
    },
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 1,
      "year": 2017
    },
    "count": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "month": 6,
      "year": 2018
    },
    "count": 3
  }
]

let result = _
  .chain(data)
  .groupBy("_id.year")
  .reduce((obj, current, index) => {
    var sortedMonths = _.sortBy(current, (v) => v._id.month), monthsArray = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
     _.map(current, (curObj, i) => monthsArray[_.get(sortedMonths, '[' + i + ']._id.month') - 1] = sortedMonths[i].count)
      return _.extend(obj, { [index]: monthsArray })
  }, {})
  .value();

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```